# How can personal styles be added to master (site.css) css file?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have some style classes that I need to use on individual aspx pages. e.g.

```
.txtbx
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    border-color:Gray;
    height:30px;
    width:250px;   
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Now, can I add such styles to the site.css file (that comes as a default when you choose to create a new web application)?

If yes how do I apply it to the individual .aspx pages since I don't have a head tag there?

I read a solution that asks me to include a content place holder in the content (.aspx) page and put the link in it. However I already have two content place holders on each of my content pages. Do I need to add a third one?

Also, would it be better to have another (external) css file to define & use my personal styles such as the one above?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add your styles to the bottom of the master `.css` file. The master page for the site is named `site.master`. That page has a `<link>` element which references the `site.css` stylesheet.

To add your custom styles to server tags, add the `CssClass` attribute and reference your custom style:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="{custom style name}">Your text here</asp:Label>
```

Comment: It doesn't work... If I move my custom styles from content page to site.css, the styles are not applied.